# Alternative to Redux reducer

Tags: javascript, redux

I'm building a library that other apps will use. My library is an extension to redux.

To keep this question as general as possible, I currently have middlewares, action creators and one reducer.

The reducer is the problem because my reducer depends on the state structure which **I, as a library developer, can't and shouldn't know**. The user may use a *combineReducers* function or other function and give my reducer's state any name he wants.

My question is - What options Redux.js library provide to library developers in a case like this; hiding reducers/other alternatives to reducers?

Comment: What does your library do? Do components need to the state your reducer produce, or is it just the middlewares?

Comment: Currently, I don't see a reason for my consumers to use the state my reducer produce. But, they will use the actions I dispatch to my reducer inside their reducers.

Comment: I can't give much details about what my library will do at this point. I'm unexpirienced with developing libraries so I may not providing the information you need to help me. please tell me if there is anything general I can tell about.

Comment: Why do you need a state and reducer?

Comment: the user gives me functions to execute before he creates his redux-store and I need to keep track on which function I executed, in which order, cancelation, failures, what function to call next, when and so on... This is barely a small piece of what I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your library in a configuration function, which requires the user to supply a [selector](https://redux.js.org/recipes/computingderiveddata), that points to place in the state that your reducer occupies.

In addition, if users access your state (not the case for you right now), you can supply selectors to use the state, without knowing it's structure.

A general non-working example:

```
const createSelectors = (mainSelector) => ({
  selectorA: (state) => mainSelector(state).dataA,
  selectorB: (state) => mainSelector(state).dataB,
});

const createMiddlewares = (actionTypes, selectors) => {
  const middlewareA = ({ getState, dispatch }) => 
    next => action => {
      const myStateA = selectors.selectorA(getState());
    };

  return {
      middlewareA
  };
};

const factory = (mainSelector = ({ myState }) => myState) => {
  const actionTypes = {};
  const actions = {};
  const reducer = () => {};
  const selectors = createSelectors(mainSelector);
  const middleware = createMiddlewares(actionTypes, selectors);

  return {
    actionTypes,
    actions,
    reducer,
    middleware,
    selectors
  };
};
```

Comment: Very nice. It's probably the only solution for keeping the reducer. I will wait to hear more answers until accepting yours. Hopefully, one will not involve the user in any way. In anyway, thanks, it's really nice :)

Comment: I'm sure it's not the only way. You can also configure a selector via a singleton, make the user place the reducer where you choose, or skip the reducer state, and manage an internal state in your middleware.

Comment: I thought about your last option, it's good but then if the user uses a store enhancer to save its state like https://github.com/elgerlambert/redux-localstorage, he wouldn't save my internal state also.

Comment: If your state should be part of the redux eco-system, you'll need a reducer.

Answer (score 0):

This package minimize needs for writing reducers, because it is using auto merge feature with actions. There is some solution with arrays too.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/micro-reducers

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of struggling with the complex Redux library. you should give it a try with https://rootzjs.org/ an alternative to redux. Its literally like a cakewalk.